# How to convert datetime string into NSDate in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have datetime format like this

```
2015-10-06 12:39:12
```

when i try to convert into nsdate it return me null. i am using below code for it.

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
 NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:user_post.modification_date];
```

Please tell me how can i convert it into correct `NSDate`?

Comment: Please use proper type of date format and convert it to NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set like this
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
```

Comment: ns date is 2015-10-06 07:09:12 +0000 as ns date what is +0000 here

Comment: Did you get +0000  ??

Comment: how to remove it from.I am using following github lib but it crash the app when nsdate is used .https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: is the default timezone Uma ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am not understanding that one.

Comment: guys i want to display the time as 2 hours ago,week ago,yesterdaay for that i have used a lib from github but i am not succeded yet

Comment: dateByAddingTimeInterval you can use with this  for 2 days later this is example                                                                                                 NSDate *nextDate = [currDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:2*(24*3600)];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    NSString *dateString1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

Comment: can you post some example

Comment: for the above example u will get date as october 08 similar

Answer (score 2):

dateString is your date in string format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set the timezone, can be the cause of the problem

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line only.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

**Z is the timeZone**